# Password-protect folder with web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have to password protect a directory on a Windows server. The page is supposed to show a list of files located in that directory. I don't have any previous knowledge (only worked with Apache before) so I've tried hacking something together by googling. (For someone who knows what they're doing I'm sure this will look ridiculous)

What I have right now is I get a login-popup but no password is working. We have a table in our SQL database for adminusers so either fetching user-login from there or having the login embedded in the config file is fine. All I need is the folder to be password-protected.

This is what I have right now in my web.config file that is located in the folder that is supposed to be password-protected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                <user name="test" password="test" />
            </credentials>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="test" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hopefully this is a simple problem and thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: You've got a mix of Basic Authentication and Forms Authentication going on it looks like. If you're expecting test/test to work in the popup, it won't. Basic authentication needs a windows username/password that is on the server I believe. You either need to go that route, or get rid of the basic authentication and implement the rest of the FormsAuthentication: Login page, etc.

Comment: Do you think it would still be possible to do a 'custom' login with sessions etc. and use "directoryBrowse"?

Comment: Is it possible in some way to use the popup window as login instead of a form?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<configuration>      
    <system.web>      
        <authentication mode="Forms">      
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">      
                <user name="test" password="test" />      
            </credentials>      
        </authentication>      
        <authorization>      
            <allow users="test" />      
            <deny users="*" />      
        </authorization>      
    </system.web>      
    <location path="admin">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>              
                <allow roles="admin" />
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location> 
    <system.webServer>      
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />      
        <security>      
            <authentication>      
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />      
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />      
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />      
            </authentication>      
        </security>      
    </system.webServer>      
</configuration>
```

You can encrypt the user information using something like this:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "sectionName" C:\Path\To\Your\Application
```

Comment: Where would I put this? In a config-file on the root or in the config-file I mentioned in my question? Where would this get user information from?

Comment: Put it in your web.config file, outside of the system.web section.

Comment: @JamesJohnson it prompts for the username and pass but when i give `test` and `test` for username and password respectively i dosent validate and keep on prompting

Comment: @JamesJohnson i want to put the password on the root dir

Comment: On Windows Server 2008R2, IIS admin complains it does not know the node "credentials"